# Laravel (5.2) Blade - How to prevent a Blade Directive in an email address from being parsed?

Tags: laravel, escaping, render, laravel-blade

**Update** This is a bug in Laravel 5.2 & 5.3

I've got a weird one here. A user's email address on our client's system has a domain with the following substring in it '@parent'. I am not including the whole thing just for the sake of privacy.

Because `@parent` is a Blade directive, Laravel seems to either process or ignore the `@parent` and strips it out of the rendered email address on the page.

For example, let's say the email address is `john@parentstuff.com`. Laravel will render the following on the page: `johnstuff.com`. See how it removes `@parent` from the email?

What I've tried to fix it:

```
1. {!! $user->email !!}

2. {{ e($user->email) }}
```

I know that this is an issue with Blade as AJAX & jQuery rendered content with this same email address is displayed just fine elsewhere on the site.

**UPDATE**

Upon further investigation, it appears this may be a bug in how Blade processes the @parent directive. I set up 3 new Laravel projects for the following versions: 5.2, 5.3 and 5.4. The project in question is a Laravel 5.2 project, FYI.

I created the following setup for each of the above mentioned versions to test the bug.

**Route**

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    $foo = 'john@parentingstuff.org';

    return view('test')->with('foo', $foo);
});
```

**Templates**

*Base*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*Test View*

```
@extends('test-base')

@section('content')
    {{$foo}}
@endsection
```

**Outputs**

- L5.2: johningstuff.org
- L5.3: johningstuff.org
- L5.4: john@parentingstuff.org

**Theories**

One very interesting case I noticed while running these tests was that having the {{$foo}} variable inside of a @section directive vs moving it outside of the @section directive led to two different outputs.

*Example*

```
{{$foo}}

@section('content')
    {{$foo}}
@endsection
```

The output of this was...

- john@parentingstuff.org
- johningstuff.org

**Conclusion**
So, does anyone know how to patch this bug in Laravel 5.2 or Laravel 5.3? Currently, upgrading to L5.4 is not an option for our client.

Anyone have any clever tricks they can think of that might help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is elsewhere. You are doing probably something more than you wrote.

Sample controller method content

```
return view('test', ['email' => 'john@parentstuff.com'];
```

Sample view:

```
Email is: {{ $email }}
```

Result is:

```
Email is: john@parentstuff.com
```

so I believe you are doing something more than you wrote.

Comment: Marcin, See my update above. Upon further investigation, it looks like this really may be a bug.

Comment: You should have initially wrote about Laravel version. It's probably a bug, but older versions are not supported any more. Now we are having 5.5 LTS and it's always recommended to use latest versions or at least latest LTS

Answer (score 0):

Something very screwy is going on in your setup, because that shouldn't be possible. Laravel processes Blade instructions *before* interpreting any variables.

I tested with a very simple example:

```
Route::get('test', function() {
    $foo = 'john@parentstuff.com';

    return view('test')->with('foo', $foo);
});
```

and a Blade template of:

```
{{ $foo }}
```

and it works just fine. `@parent` is not interpreted.

Comment: For further debugging, take a look at the Blade-interpreted code that'll be cached somewhere in `storage/framework/views`, and check the source code that's being output.

Comment: You're right, something very screwy must be going on. I just tried running the same test on a brand new, barebones blade template and it rendered properly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: See my update above. Upon further investigation, it looks like this really may be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Laravel verions prior to 5.4. See the following:

- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10068
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/16033

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Laravel 5.1 too.
A quick solution could be to change the **@** sign to 
    `&#64;` 
to fix it.